# How to create app for iphone using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, iphone, visual-studio-2008

I want to create a native app/web app which works on iPhone, iPad. I am having Visual Studio with me. Can you please guide me how to create a app using .net. Any other framework/tool which I can install on windows also appreciated.

Thanks

-Ankit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/). It's your only way of building iPhone Apps with .NET. It is not free, but it's not expensive either. There is a cheaper student edition if you are one.

Right now there is no Visual Studio support, but they are working on it. And you still need a Mac with XCode for testing/deploying purposes.

Comment: Hi Pablo, Thanks for your comments and time. I have already tried my hands on Monotouch but I am facing lots of trouble using it. It is not showing iPhone application in for Windows version. So I installed it in Mac system and there it's not able to work properly. Some compatibility issues are there which I am trying to figure out. Also I have tried ipFaces, Tersus, Component One and still finding some other things. These tools doesn't suits on my requirement. :(. If anyone knows any other tools then please let me know..